# How to print exact sql query when using hibernate 3 with logback

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, logback

I am using logback as logging framework and hibernate 3 as ORM tool. I want to print all the SQL queries exactly the same as it executes in the mysql DB.

I tried with show_sql=true parameter though it only prints the sql but no binding values with it.

I've gone through the earlier posts and have also tried to put the logger in logback to get the desired result but no luck.

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.loader.hql" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="hibernateLogger" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="hibernateLogger" />
</logger>
```

Even after defining these loggers and the appenders, sql w/o bindings are being printed on console rather than desired logfile

Answer (score 0):

Add this logger

```
 <logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder"> 
   <level value="TRACE"/>
 </logger>
```